# Doubt with definition of divergence sequence to $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Good night i have a doubt with definition of sequence diverge to $-\infty$

I know the definition when $\{x_n\}\rightarrow+\infty$ is this:

For all $l>0$ exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that is $n\geq N$ then $|x_n|>l$

but for $-\infty$ i'm stuck. can someone help me with that?

Comment: By the way, for your definition of $x_n\to +\infty$, you should remove the absolute signs from $x_n$. Otherwise, you would count a sequence like $-1,-2,-3,-4,\ldots$ as going to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is that for all $\color{blue}{l < 0}$, there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that if $n\ge N$, then $\color{blue}{x_n< l}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n \rightarrow -\infty$.

Then $y_n:= -x_n \rightarrow +\infty$(plausible?).

For $l >0$, real, there is a $N$ s t. for $n \ge N$

$y_n =-x_n  >  l$, i.e. $ x_n < - l$.

Finally:

For $L:=-l <0$, real, there is a $N$ s.t.

for $n \ge N$

$x_n < -l = L$.